# latex bibtex bibliography splits citations across pages

Tags: latex, bibtex

I'm just working on my thesis in latex. I use apacite and a bibtex document for my bibliography. However, some references are split up across pages as can be seen in the image. how can I prevent this from happening? Already tried to set a penalty for this, but this did not work out yet.

[image: split up reference]

Comment: Which penalty did you set?

Comment: I used the \widowpenalty and \clubpenalty, but didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Did you try setting them to "infinity", i.e. `10000`? See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91686/preventing-page-breaks-from-occurring-in-bibliography-items/92690#92690

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51257/how-can-i-force-bibliography-items-not-to-be-split-across-pages/51261#51261